# Is there a way to populate a column based on values associated with another column in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a very large data-set at the moment that I'm trying to work with, but I need the blanks populated before I can effectively do so. A mock-up example of what I'm working with looks something like Ex 1. The "Name" is only populating 1 value in the "Item" column for each "Team".

Is it possible to assign the value in the "Name" column to all rows with the respective "Team" number its associated with to look something like Ex 2? I would be reading in an excel file.

I'm new to pandas, and I'm unsure what to look up specifically to find this answer, so I apologize if this has been asked before.

```
Ex1

 Team    Item      Name
 1       Credit    
 1       Debit     Bob
 1       Etc       
 2       Credit    
 2       Debit     Steve
 2       Etc       

Ex2

 Team    Item      Name
 1       Credit    Bob
 1       Debit     Bob
 1       Etc       Bob
 2       Credit    Steve
 2       Debit     Steve
 2       Etc       Steve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `groupby` with `ffill().bfill()` chain.

```
df['Name']=df.groupby('Team').Name.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
Out[262]: 
   Team    Item   Name
0     1  Credit    Bob
1     1   Debit    Bob
2     1     Etc    Bob
3     2  Credit  Steve
4     2   Debit  Steve
5     2     Etc  Steve
```